# php login form using if

Tags: php, html, authentication

I've got a PHP login form but it doesn't work. The code for the form is:

```html
<html>
<body>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
<table> 
 <tr>
  <td>
   username:
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" name="username">   </td>
  
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   Password:
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="password" name="password">
  </td>
  
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Login"/>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
    
    
    
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the login.php is:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))
{

if($_POST['username'] == "test" . "admin")
{
    echo "username correct!<br/>";
    $user = true;

}
else
{
    echo "username wrong!<br/>";
    $user = FALSE;
}
if($_POST['password'] == "test" . "admin")
    {
        echo "password correct!<br/>";
        $pass = true;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "password failed!<br/>";
        $pass = FALSE;
    }
    if($user == TRUE && $pass == TRUE)
    {
        echo "Login succeded!";
        echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='5; url= www.google.com'>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Login failed";
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
                , 'history.go(-1);'
            , '</script>'
            ;
    }
}
?>
```

I want to get some more usernames and passwords in it.

You can see it live at http://dshelmondgames.r4u.nl/login/

Comment: How exactly does it not work? What is the problem?

Comment: If you want to test the login procedure against more usernames you might think about storing them in a database. Why are you concatonating "test" . "admin" What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you login with user and password `testadmin`, because you concat the strings. If you want to allow `admin/admin` and `test/test`, you have to build an array for easy use:

```
$users = Array("admin" => "admin", "test" => "test");
```

Then you can use:

```
if(isset($users[$_POST['username']]))
...
if($users[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password'])
```

This will not work either:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
                , 'history.go(-1);'
            , '</script>'
            ;
```

Use:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
            . 'history.go(-1);'
        . '</script>'
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnt exactly mention what is going wrong. Well, it definitely works but that kind of PHP login code is not encouraged and not at all secured!
It's better if you write a code using some database like MariaDB and SQL. You can find the link here: 
https://studio.youtube.com/video/aK6lSefugFs/

And yea after login success, you have to give it as this

```
if($user == TRUE && $pass == TRUE)
    {
        echo "Login succeded!";
        echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='5; url= https://www.google.com'>";
    }
```

if you didn't write https:// in front of google.com, it will search for google.com page in your directory which is obviously not found.